# Blender saving baked internal normal image always in .EXR

Tags: export, texture-baking, normal-map, .exr, packed-data

i am using the addon *simple bake* for baking pbr maps for objects.

If i use *External Data > Unpack all into files* to export an FBX with image textures, blender is saving all images as .PNG except the normal map which is .EXR.

To save file-space i want to unpack as .PNG and cannot figure out to tell blender to always use .PNG instead of .EXR for normals.

The packed image texture has the following properties:
[image]

This has worked before and suddenly i only get exr. A workaround is to save only the normal individually by *Image > Save As* (here is openEXR selected by default) and change it to PNG, but this is very impractical.

I also tried to set the default format under *Output Properties > Output* to PNG with no luck.

I hope someone can help me how to set blender up to always save the normal image in a specific format (.png for my case)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I noticed that when I created a new image to bake to, I'd left off the .png. I just created a new image and included the .png at the end and I was good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)